# Save query results to .csv with PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, export-to-csv

I have the following query running and I am looking at the best way to export the data to a .csv or .xls file.

```
<?php

    $channels = ee()->db->select('channel_titles.entry_id, channel_titles.title, channel_data.field_id_164')
    ->from('channel_titles')
    ->join('channel_data', 'channel_titles.entry_id = channel_data.entry_id')
    ->where(array(
            'channel_titles.channel_id' => '12',
        ))
    ->or_where(array(
            'channel_titles.channel_id' => '31',
        ))
    ->get();

    if ($channels->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        $i = 0;
        foreach($channels->result_array() as $row)
        {
            $i++;
            echo $row['field_id_164'].",".$row['title']."<br />\n";
        }
        echo $i;
    }       

?>
```

I have tried a few methods but cannot seem to figure out the best option.

Comment: Why do you need to save a query into csv file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classic echo explode(',',$col) etc way is fine, but you can also write directly to the csv file using php's built in functions.

```
    $filename = 'test.csv';
    $file = fopen($filename,"w");
    if ($channels->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach($channels->result_array() as $key => $row) {
            if ($key==0) fputcsv($file, array_keys((array)$row)); // write column headings, added extra brace
            foreach ($row as $line) {
                $line = (array) $line;
                fputcsv($file, $line);
            }
        }
    }   

    fclose($file);
```

edit:

If you want to download/view the file instantly you have to set the headers.

```
    $filename = 'test.csv';

    header('Content-type: application/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $filename);
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: UTF-8");

    $file = fopen('php://output', 'a');
    if ($channels->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach($channels->result_array() as $key => $row) {
            if ($key==0) fputcsv($file, array_keys((array)$row)); // write column headings, added extra brace
            foreach ($row as $line) {
                $line = (array) $line;
                fputcsv($file, $line);
            }
        }
    }  

    fclose($file);
```

Comment: Should this download the csv file itself? I have added the code but I receive a blank page.